# convert php array to string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert a PHP array to a string. This is what the array looks like when I `print_r`:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
           [0] => Some text
         ) 
  [1] => Array (
           [0] => some more text
         ) 
  [2] => Array (
           [0] => SomeText
         )
)
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
foreach($a as $b){
        $c.= ", $b";
}
```

But that keeps coming back with `Array Array Array`.

Comment: how would you like the array to be represented?

Comment: I dont understand why would anyone downvote without saying any reason.

Comment: They are all wrong and almost the same answer.

Comment: @AbraCadaver...so can you remove the downvote now that mine was correct :P

Comment: So where are we with this question now?

Comment: I would argue that the solution provided in the linked duplicate overcomplicates things for this question.

Comment: @Devon *I would argue* Don't argue, if you disagree and say that the dupe wouldn't answer OP's question, then press the reopen button.

Comment: @Rizier123, already did.  But I doubt it's going to get re-opened, my simple solution was downvoted 2 times before you correctly indented the array.  Thanks for the indentation by the way,  I really screwed the pooch on my attempt to indent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($a as $b){
        $c.= ", ".$b[0];
}
```

What you have is actually a multidimensional array.  So *$b* is still an array in this scenario and *0* is the offset you need to retrieve, so therefore you need `$b[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize your string and then go through each value with [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) and append it to the string. At the end just remove the last comma with [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$str = "";
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v)use(&$str){$str .= $v . ",";});
echo $str = rtrim($str, ",");
```

Advantages? It doesn't matter how many dimensions your array has.

Answer (score 0):

So given the sample array, it is multi-dimensional.  If you want to display the inner array values separated by commas:

```
foreach($a as $v) {
    echo implode(', ', $v);
}
```

If all need to be joined into a comma separated list then:

```
foreach($a as $v) {
    $result[] = implode(', ', $v);
}
echo implode(', ', $result);
```

Comment: I think you're first example is wrong in this case.  They are stored in offsets 0,1,2 not all under the first offset 0.

Comment: Yes, I hate when it's not indented.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was wrong, I just indented it.  It was not how I thought it was.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I was right, lol.  I just messed up the indentation... wow confusing post.

Comment: this would still miss a comma between array entries.

Comment: @Kathir: If that's what they want kinda hard to tell.  Edited...

Answer (score 0):

That is basically and array that contains arrays, so you need to iterate over the inner arrays.

```
    foreach($a as $b){
    // b is array here
      foreach($b as $actualValues){
      $c.= ",".$actualValues[0];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You have got an Array, consisting of Arrays with one Element containing your Text. So you are trying to print an Array which contains your string. Try it like this:

```
foreach($a as $b){
    $c.= ", ".$b[0];
}
```